# Mongo 2.6 Text Search Gone Crazy

Tags: python, mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-query

I'm using Mongodb text search on 2.6. For this case, Mongodb is completely acting crazy. I'm sure this is a bug.

I'm running two queries like this

```
db.command(
                    'text',
                    'tweets',
                    search='kejriwal ak4pm arvindkejriwal arvind',
                    limit=500000,
                    project={'_id': 1, 'rT': 1, 'ts': 1},
                    # filter=basicFilterQuery
                )['results']
```

This query is giving me **0 results**.

But when I run this query:

```
db.command(
                        'text',
                        'tweets',
                        search='kejriwal ak4pm arvind',
                        limit=500000,
                        project={'_id': 1, 'rT': 1, 'ts': 1},
                        # filter=basicFilterQuery
                    )['results']
```

This query is giving me **15K results****.

This seems wrong to me, since **first query string is more inclusive then the second one and should be returning more documents**.

Can anyone tell me what's going on in here?

Comment: I'd recommending that you open an issue with these details: https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Answer (score 0):

Also check your language settings. Default is English, this will affect the full text search results.